# How to convert UNIX timestamp to the given timezone in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timezone, unix-timestamp

I use Spark 1.6.2

I have epochs like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|unix_timestamp|UTC                |Europe/Helsinki    |
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1491771599    |2017-04-09 20:59:59|2017-04-09 23:59:59|
|1491771600    |2017-04-09 21:00:00|2017-04-10 00:00:00|
|1491771601    |2017-04-09 21:00:01|2017-04-10 00:00:01|
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The default timezone is the following on the Spark machines:

#timezone = DefaultTz: **Europe/Prague**, SparkUtilTz: **Europe/Prague**

the output of

```scala
logger.info("#timezone = DefaultTz: {}, SparkUtilTz: {}", TimeZone.getDefault.getID, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.defaultTimeZone.getID)
```

I want to count the timestamps grouped by date and hour in the given timezone (now it is **Europe/Helsinki +3hours**).

What I expect:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
|date      |hour     |count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|2017-04-09|23       |1    |
|2017-04-10|0        |2    |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

Code (using `from_utc_timestamp`):

```scala
def getCountsPerTime(sqlContext: SQLContext, inputDF: DataFrame, timeZone: String, aggr: String): DataFrame = {

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val onlyTime = inputDF.select(
         from_utc_timestamp($"unix_timestamp".cast(DataTypes.TimestampType),  timeZone).alias("time")
    )

    val visitsPerTime =
        if (aggr.equalsIgnoreCase("hourly")) {
            onlyTime.groupBy(
                date_format($"time", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("date"),
                date_format($"time", "H").cast(DataTypes.IntegerType).alias("hour"),
            ).count()
        } else if (aggr.equalsIgnoreCase("daily")) {
            onlyTime.groupBy(
                date_format($"time", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("date")
            ).count()
        }

    visitsPerTime.show(false)

    visitsPerTime
}
```

What I get:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
|date      |hour     |count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|2017-04-09|22       |1    |
|2017-04-09|23       |2    |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

Trying to wrap it with `to_utc_timestamp`:

```scala
def getCountsPerTime(sqlContext: SQLContext, inputDF: DataFrame, timeZone: String, aggr: String): DataFrame = {

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val onlyTime = inputDF.select(
        to_utc_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp($"unix_timestamp".cast(DataTypes.TimestampType), timeZone), DateTimeUtils.defaultTimeZone.getID).alias("time")
    )

    val visitsPerTime = ... //same as above

    visitsPerTime.show(false)

    visitsPerTime
}
```

What I get:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
|tradedate |tradehour|count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|2017-04-09|20       |1    |
|2017-04-09|21       |2    |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

How to get the expected result?

Comment: Quick terminology lesson: `"I have epocs like this"`  - no, you don't.  You have "Unix Timestamps".  An "epoch" is the start of something, in this case the epoch is fixed at `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.  There are many different epochs used in computing, but Unix Time only has one.

Comment: Also, you can supply an answer to your own question. Don't just drop it in comments please.  Though, I'm not sure how what you put in comments addresses the question you asked, as you asked for conversion to a specific time zone, but you seem to be working with the system default time zone there.

Answer (score 8):

Your codes are not working for me so I couldn't replicate the last two outputs you got.

But I am going to provide you some hints on how you can achieve the output you expected

I am assuming you already have `dataframe` as

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|unix_timestamp|UTC                  |Europe/Helsinki      |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|1491750899    |2017-04-09 20:59:59.0|2017-04-09 23:59:59.0|
|1491750900    |2017-04-09 21:00:00.0|2017-04-10 00:00:00.0|
|1491750901    |2017-04-09 21:00:01.0|2017-04-10 00:00:01.0|
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I got this `dataframe` by using following code

```scala
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    
val inputDF = Seq(
      "2017-04-09 20:59:59",
      "2017-04-09 21:00:00",
      "2017-04-09 21:00:01"
    ).toDF("unix_timestamp")
    
val onlyTime = inputDF.select(
      unix_timestamp($"unix_timestamp").alias("unix_timestamp"),
      from_utc_timestamp($"unix_timestamp".cast(DataTypes.TimestampType),  "UTC").alias("UTC"),
      from_utc_timestamp($"unix_timestamp".cast(DataTypes.TimestampType),  "Europe/Helsinki").alias("Europe/Helsinki")
    )
    
onlyTime.show(false)
```

Once you have above `dataframe`, getting the output `dataframe` that you desire would require you to `split` the date, `groupby` and `count` as below

```scala
onlyTime.select(split($"Europe/Helsinki", " ")(0).as("date"), split(split($"Europe/Helsinki", " ")(1).as("time"), ":")(0).as("hour"))
          .groupBy("date", "hour").agg(count("date").as("count"))
      .show(false)
```

The resulting `dataframe` is

```
+----------+----+-----+
|date      |hour|count|
+----------+----+-----+
|2017-04-09|23  |1    |
|2017-04-10|00  |2    |
+----------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `"spark.sql.session.timeZone"` before the action seems to be reliable. Using this setting we can be sure that the timestamps that we use afterwards- does actually represent the time in the specified time zone. Without it (if we use `from_unixtime` or `timestamp_seconds`) we can't be sure which time zone is represented. Both those functions represent the current system time zone. And if afterwards we used `to_utc_timestamp` or `from_utc_timestamp`, we would only get a shift from the current system time zone. UTC does not necessarily come into play with the latter functions. This is why explicitly setting a time zone can be reliable. One thing to keep in mind is that the action(s) must be performed before `spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")`.

---

**Scala**

Input df:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val inputDF = Seq(1491771599L,1491771600L,1491771601L).toDF("unix_timestamp")
inputDF.show()
//  +--------------+
//  |unix_timestamp|
//  +--------------+
//  |    1491771599|
//  |    1491771600|
//  |    1491771601|
//  +--------------+
```

Result:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Helsinki")

val ts = from_unixtime($"unix_timestamp")
val DF = inputDF.groupBy(to_date(ts).alias("date"), hour(ts).alias("hour")).count()
DF.show()
//  +----------+----+-----+                                                         
//  |      date|hour|count|
//  +----------+----+-----+
//  |2017-04-09|  23|    1|
//  |2017-04-10|   0|    2|
//  +----------+----+-----+

spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
```

---

**PySpark**

Input df:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1491771599,),(1491771600,),(1491771601,)], ['unix_timestamp'])
df.show()
#  +--------------+
#  |unix_timestamp|
#  +--------------+
#  |    1491771599|
#  |    1491771600|
#  |    1491771601|
#  +--------------+
```

Result:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Helsinki")

ts = F.from_unixtime('unix_timestamp')
df_agg = df.groupBy(F.to_date(ts).alias('date'), F.hour(ts).alias('hour')).count()
df_agg.show()
#  +----------+----+-----+
#  |      date|hour|count|
#  +----------+----+-----+
#  |2017-04-09|  23|    1|
#  |2017-04-10|   0|    2|
#  +----------+----+-----+

spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
```